# How can I send a message from one activity to another in real time

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activities, when I open `Activity2`, the `Activity1` won't be closed. In `Activity1` I have a handle that post a code (`handler.postDelayed()`), when this code run I need my `Activity2` be notified in order to execute a other code too.

My question is: How can I send this message to `Activity2` without reopening it.

I tried use an `Intent` with a specific action and catch it in `onNewIntent()` in `Activity2`; it works but the problem is that this reopen my `Activity2`. And I can't save the data in SharedPrefs cause my `postDelayed()` have no fix time, then I'd have to be checking all the time.

Does anyone know how I can send this message when my `postDelayed()` runs and how I catch it in `Activity2` without reopening it? Please if possible post a example or a link to one.

Really thanks...

Comment: use single instance mode when starting the activity.

Comment: You can send a broadcast message from your first activity to your second activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a simple solutions, like said @njzk2, was only add

```
<activity ..
      android:launchMode= "singleInstance" />
```

or

```
<activity ..
      android:launchMode= "singleTask" />
```

(both works).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using an `Activity` to handle long-running code, you should probably look into creating an [`IntentService`](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/index.html) to handle your background code. The `IntentService` can broadcast a new `Intent` when it is finished running the code. Have your first `Activity` start the `Service`, then instantiate a [`BroadcastReceiver`](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/report-status.html) in your second `Activity` to listen for updates from the `Service`.

> Sending an broadcast `Intent` doesn't start or resume an `Activity`.
>   The `BroadcastReceiver` for an `Activity` receives and processes
>   `Intent` objects even when your app is in the background, but doesn't
>   force your app to the foreground.

Comment: I can't use a service. My activity1 is the home activity and the activity2 may be opened or not. So I need to verify before send a message from 1 to 2. And if the app were closed any message should be send. But thanks any way.

Comment: @Emily The case you describe is exactly what a `Service` is meant for, as a `Service` can persist after the application is terminated, while an `Activity` cannot. I don't know what you mean by needing to "verify before" you send the the message, but unless it is verified by user interaction, it can be done directly in a `Service`.